# How are default permissions determined (on OS X)?

Tags: permissions, osx, umask, xattr, defaults

My (limited) understanding of basic Unix is that any files that are created will be created based on the permissions of the creating user. In particular, the group assigned will be the creating user's "default" group. But on OS X (10.8.2) I see different behavior.

Even though my default group is my user account (my GID as listed by `id`), if  I create a file in a directory with

```
drwx---r-x   MyName   MyName
```

or with

```
drwx------   MyName   MyName
```

it has

```
-rw-r--r--   MyName   MyName
```

while if I create a file in a director with

```
drwxr-xr-x   MyName   staff
```

it has

```
-rw-r--r--   MyName   staff
```

There are no extended attributes on any of the these directories, yet they behave as if something like `directory_inherit` and `file_inherit` are set, and as if read permission should always be given.

Where are these default policies set in OS X (Mountain Lion)? How can they be configured?

---

I'm happy with the inheritance of group, but would ideally like files created in `-r` directories to be `-r` also; and would like "others" to never have any access. I suspect I can do something with `umask` to get this latter behavior, but I'd still like to be sure and to know where why the group is inherited from the containing directory.

Answer (score -1):

I've no answer for this, but have noticed the same issue at:
http://bugs.gnu.org/14024#41

I would love to know what is setting the group to that of the containing directory.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://unix.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://unix.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment).